# Size of different program elements in C++

Tags: c++

When does memory get allocated to a data type, class and function? At the time of declaration or at the time of definition?

Also is there a way to know the sizeof function?

Comment: Did you mean size of function's pointer or size of functions' code size?

Comment: I mean size of function.I think pointer to function has the same size oa that of simple pointers.Am I right? But please answer the first part of the question.

Comment: Pointer to functions may not be the same size as simple pointers. It's compiler dependent and may grow up to 16 bytes. (Pointer to virtual functions are bigger)

Comment: The way your question is asked I deduce you think of the program execution as "source code -> running program", while it's more like "source-code -> compiler (+ linker) -> binary image -> OS loader -> running program". Declarations and definitions are compile-time concepts.

Comment: @ybungalobill:Thanks.But  I am not thinking like that.I just want to know when is the memory allocated :at the time of declaration or at the time of definition?

Comment: @gautam: your question doesn't make any sense because the memory is allocated neither at the definition nor at the declaration.

Comment: In K&R book of c it has been written:Definition'' refers to the place where the variable is created or assigned storage; ``declaration'' refers to places where the nature of the variable is stated but no storage is allocated.I respect your knowledge,But can you please elaborate this line.

Comment: @gautam: 1) K&R is no way a C++ book. 2) what they're saying is an analogy used to explain the difference between definitions and declarations. You should not infer anything about the *storage* allocated in *real world*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Size of different program elements in C++
>
> When does memory get allocated to a data type, class and function? At the time of declaration or at the time of definition?

A data type is just an abstract notion understood by the compiler. When a variable of that type is needed, memory must be allocated. The:

- amount of memory - which is available at compile time using the `sizeof` *operator* (it's not a function) - is determined by the compiler: for inbuilt types it's fixed based on their binary representation, for user-defined types it's basically a "recursive" sum of the data member's individual sizes adjusted for alignment/packing)
- An actual address may be determined at:

  - compile time (typically global and `static` variables) [further details in comments]
  - at run-time (for heap-allocated variables),
  - in a hybrid run-time-stack-frame-relative way for local variables
  - at load-time or in a base-address-relative way (for global/extern/static symbols in dynamically loaded libraries).

Classes are just user-defined data types, and follow these same rules, though for classes it's possible for the size to be unknown if a declaration has been seen by the compiler, but the definition is further into the source code: until the compiler sees the definition it can't calculate the size of the object, and you can make very limited use of the class identifier - creating pointers and references that will point to an instance, but not actual variables of that type.

> Also is there any way to know the sizeof function?

Again - it's an operator which basically injects the compile-time constant size value that the compiler's calculated. As such, there is no `sizeof` function in any machine-code object the compiler produces.

Comment: *actual address may be determined at: **compile time (typically global and static variables)***. How?

Comment: @Nawaz: Well, more precisely: the compiler decides whether to put them in zero-initialised or uninitialised memory, and within those blocks determines their memory address (loosely, it lays out all such variables successively in the block). For some executable formats / OS / loaders this is a segment-register-relative (but the segment registers often don't need to be constantly dynamically adjusted the way stack registers are), for a few old systems it may be absolute, and on yet others it may be load-time-tweaked.

Comment: But that alone doesn't determine the *actual address* of *global and static variables*. As far as I understand untill the OS loads the image in the process address space, the actual address of any symbol, (variable and function) cannot be known.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think our disconnect relates to the differences between virtual, segment-relative and physical addressing. From the perspective of the generated machine code, in many environments the compilers can rely on known loader setup of virtual and/or data-segment registers, hard-coding addresses for data that will not need to be individually tweaked during loading. For example, every program may be seemingly loaded at address "0", with execution starting at a known offset. It's true that the *physical* memory address that "0" (or whatever) translates to inside the CPU is not absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Memory gets allocated at the time of definition, for example,

(header constructs left out)

- In `foo.h`: `extern int bar;` - declaration
- In `foo.cpp`: `int bar = 0;` -definition (albeit global)

The declaration lets the compiler 'know' that a variable/class/function exists, whereas a definition actually 'defines' the variable/class/function.

The implementation of the `sizeof()` operator is compiler and implementation dependent - there's no easy way to find its implementation.

Comment: int bar is a definition by the way.And please answer to what Am I asking?

Comment: No if you want a declaration without definition you have to type the keyword 'extern'.

Comment: Oh god. This stuff always mixes me up. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

1. All auto variables are allocated when program flow enters its scope. Global variables respect this rule too. All of them are allocated on program startup.
2. A function's actual size cannot be determined. On the assembly level your function may be broken into many pieces by the compiler. Also your function code may contain other inlined functions.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to the questions are:

1. Definition (for functions it depends on the kind of function, if it is a delay load DLL file for example, perhaps when the DLL file is loaded)
2. no

Answer (score 0):

A variable gets allocated when it enters scope. There is no sizeof(function), and allocated memory belongs to the heap.